# Get app link referer

Tags: android, android-intent, http-referer, applinks

I implemented app links. Is there any way to get the referrer from which the user came to my app without adding additional information to URL?

Or at least any way to filter open intent only from some source, for example, email or messenger, but not from the browser.

I am not interested in install referrer.

I need to recognize if the user came from the email, google, or from my website.

Thanks!